# How to fix WARNING: Module cassandra ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.1/mods-available

Tags: php, cassandra

How to fix this error,

> WARNING: Module cassandra ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.1/mods-available

I got this error while installing php driver for cassandra libraray using deb package.

http://downloads.datastax.com/php-driver/ubuntu/16.04/cassandra/v1.3.2/

```
cannot open /include/cassandra.h (No such file or directory) configure: error: not supported. Driver version 2.7.0+ required (found ) ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/cassandra/configure --with-php-con
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-tried and was able to resolve it.

one trick here:

```
to avoid error

(cannot open /include/cassandra.h (No such file or directory) configure: error: not supported. Driver version 2.7.0+ required (found ) ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/cassandra/configure --with-php-con
    ) is I executed all command at '/' directory not in home or any other directory.

###################

sudo git clone https://github.com/datastax/php-driver.git
cd php-driver/
git submodule update --init
sudo chmod -R 777 /php-driver/
cd ext
sudo ./install.sh
sudo phpize
sudo ./configure
sudo make install
```

After that added to php.ini

```
; DataStax PHP Driver for Apache Cassandra
extension=cassandra.so
```

And restarted apache2 using

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and checked for php modules usnig

```
php -m //it reflects cassandra module
```